# Get Esxi networks usage via Pyvmomi

Tags: vmware, esxi, pyvmomi

I'm stuck trying to retrieve the network usage per vnic (packets sent/received) from Esxi hosts
I have been able to get network names and their properties but i can't figure out how to get the real usage.
In the general API explorer I found this object "vim.host.RuntimeInfo.PnicNetworkResourceInfo"
but it returns unset even if I am using pyvmomi v6.7.
I am authenticate with full admin provileges
Can someone please tell me in which managed object should I check?
I can post the link about the doc talking about that object that returns unset for me

https://vdc-repo.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/fe08899f-1eec-4d8d-b3bc-a6664c168c2c/7fdf97a1-4c0d-4be0-9d43-2ceebbc174d9/doc/vim.host.RuntimeInfo.PnicNetworkResourceInfo.html

Comment: Did you find a way to get network traffic for ESXi host?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to switch over to using the PerformanceManager object and having it reference the host/s in question.

Here's the available network counters: https://code.vmware.com/apis/358/vsphere/doc/network_counters.html

Here's a sample script to start interacting with the PerformanceManager (albeit with a VM): https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples/blob/master/samples/vm_perf_example.py

Comment: Now I have another problem,  I answered to my question to make it visible to someone

Comment: Are you able to extract network transmitted and received data of an ESXi host?